# How to show all the Users who have liked my post

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I apologize for the newbie questions still relatively new to rails. I'm trying to show all the users who have liked my specific posts. I took a look at this similar question [How to list the users who LIKE a given Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435778/how-to-list-the-users-who-like-a-given-post]) but it couldn't solve my problem. I listed below all the relevant simple code - thank you so much guys!!

**Items Controller**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]
    before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :share]

    def index    
        @items = Item.order("created_at DESC")
    end
end
```

**Index.html.erb**

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= image_tag current_user.avatar, width: 70, class: "css-style"  %>
    <br>
    <strong><%= link_to current_user.username, current_user, class: "profile-style" %></strong>
    <ul><!--Trying to show all the users who have liked my specific posts here -->
    <% item.likes.each do |like| %>
  <li> <%= link_to(like.user.username, like.user) %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to 'Login/SignUp', new_user_session_path %>
<% end %>
<% @items.each do |item| %>
    <%= image_tag item.avatar.url(:medium), class: "block" %>
    <div>
        <%= render partial: "likes", locals: {item: item} %></span><%= item.likes_count %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**Items.rb**

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :likes, :counter_cache => true
    belongs_to :user
    has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]
    has_many :likes
    has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

    def likes?(post)
        post.likes.where(user_id: id).any?
    end
end
```

**Users Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :share]
    def index
        @users = User.all
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @items = Item.all
    end

    private

    def set_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def item_params
        params.require(:item).permit(:product, :amount, :city_id, :avatar)
    end
end
```

**Like.rb**

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :item, :counter_cache => true
belongs_to :user
end
```

**Likes Controller**

```
class Items::LikesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :set_book

def create

    @item.likes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create


    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to @item}
        format.js
    end
end


def destroy
    @item.likes.where(user_id: current_user.id).destroy_all

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to @item}
        format.js
    end
end
private
def set_book
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
end
end
```

**Logs**

```
Processing by ItemsController#index as HTML
```

Rendering items/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" ORDER BY created_at DESC
  Rendered items/index.html.erb within layouts/application (287.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 313ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `item' for #<#:0x007f9afbfd14f0>
Did you mean?  item_url
               items_url
               item_path
               @items):
     5: 
     6: **<%= link_to current_user.username, current_user, class: "profile-style" %>**
     7:

  8:         <% item.likes.each do |like| %>
       9:
- <%= link_to(like.user.username, like.user) %>
  10: <% end %>
      11:

app/views/items/index.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_items_index_html_erb___2312434021832006771_70151814680620'
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (8.3ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.3ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (94.4ms)

Comment: In your index.html.erb you have : "<li> <%= link_to(l.user.username, l.user) %></li>" I think it should be : <li> <%= link_to(like.user.username, like.user) %></li>  You never create the variable "l" anywhere but in that loop you are using |like|.  Does that fix it?

Comment: @RockwellRice thank you so much for your response. when i do that I get this error undefined method `likes' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple mistake. I think the problem is with your partial.. you're calling the partial with `locals` and inside your template code you are referring to it with `@item` instead of `item`, here `item` is not an `instance` variable.

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
    <%= image_tag item.avatar.url(:medium), class: "block" %>
    <div>
        <%= render partial: "likes", locals: {item: item} %></span><%= item.likes_count %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The thing is when you render a partial with `locals` you need to use the locals as normal variables not as `instance` variables.

This should work.

```
<% item.likes.each do |like| %>
      <li> <%= link_to(like.user.username, like.user) %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Minato thank you so much for your response. I followed your logic perfectly. I also added this line into my items controller - @item = Item.find(params[:id]) . But I get this error when I refresh Couldn't find Item with 'id'=

Comment: can you post your log?

Comment: Absolutely - 
Processing by ItemsController#index as HTML
  Item Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

Comment: @omar you don't need to define @item in your controller, you just have a typo in your partial. Change `<% @item.likes.each do |like| %>` to be `<% item.likes.each do |like| %>`: then it will use the local you're passing in when you render the partial.

Comment: Minato thanks for clarrifying when I do that though - I'm getting this error: undefined local variable or method `item' for #<#<Class:0x007f9b006b6190>:0x007f9b020fbca8>
Did you mean?  item_url
               items_url
               item_path
               @items

Comment: Also here is the updated logs when I do that - Processing by ItemsController#index as HTML
  Rendering items/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Item Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" ORDER BY created_at DESC
  Rendered items/index.html.erb within layouts/application (291.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 317ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

Comment: @Omar I need a complete log without this > you don't need to define `@item` in your controller, you just have a typo in your partial. Change <% `@item.likes.each do |like| %> to be <% item.likes.each do |like| %>`: then it will use the local you're passing in when you render the partial

Comment: Minato, I have changed it just as you suggested but I keep getting an error undefined local variable or method `item' for #<#<Class:0x007f9b006b6190>:0x007f9afbfd14f0>
Did you mean?  item_url
               items_url
               item_path
               @items

Comment: @Omar don't change `@item` to `item` in your `index.html.erb` file. I did not suggest you to change it in `index.html.erb`

Comment: @Minato okay but didn't you tell me I had to because it was a typo

Comment: @Omar it was someone else's comment

Comment: Oh got it so when I do <% @item.likes.each do |like| %> as you suggest @Minato I get this undefined method `likes' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131283/discussion-between-minato-and-omar).

Comment: Minato had the correct solution - if anyone is stuck in a similar bind - you'll need to first change your items controller -  `if current_user.present? 
  @likers = Item.where("user_id", current_user.id).map(&:users).flatten
  end`. Then have a line like this present in your index.html.erb - `<%- @likers.each do |liker| %> 
<%= liker.username %> 
<% end %>`

Answer (score 1):

In `items/index.html.erb` you are referencing `@item.likes.each` on line 9, but the instance variable `@item` has not been set in `items_controller#index`. You have only defined `@items`, hence the error you are receiving about `nil` not responding to `#likes`.

If you want to see the likes for all items, there are a number of ways to achieve this with Arel.

Comment: coreyward thank you so much for responding - I added this line to my items controller  @item = Item.find(params[:id])  but when I do that and refresh the page i get this error Couldn't find Item with 'id'=

Comment: Because `items#index` is an index method that probably doesn't have an `id` parameter (which makes sense as you aren't viewing an Item, but a list of Items). Again, if you want to see the likes for all items, that's a separate thing you're trying to retrieve.

Comment: At this point, it's clear you're into the weeds and whipping up a dish of copy pasta. It's okay, we all have that happen. My best suggestion is this: grab a fresh cup of coffee, go back to the Rails Guides, and start from the top reviewing.

Comment: Thanks coreyward - I'm powering through just a little bit more. Its strange because all I want to do is see who liked my posts in a little list. I get your comment on the id parameter that's why I defined one in my controller
 @itemlike = Item.find(params[:id]) 
 but I was still getting an error Couldn't find Item with 'id'=

Answer (score 0):

You need one more table(model) "likes" and association [has-many-through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). Something like this:

```
class Item
  has_many :likes
  has_many :users, through: :likes
end

class Like
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end

class User
  has_many :likes
  has_many :items
  has_many :liked_items, through: :likes
end
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response. I already had a like model and in my item.rb - I had the following (has_many :likes, :counter_cache => true) can I just modify your code like this has_many : likers, through: likes, :counter_cache => true)

Comment: just saw your most recent edits I get this error though "undefined method `likes' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: I just tried it. I still get that undefined method `likes' for nil:NilClass. Im seeing this in my logs (updated question)